# How to test Mongo connection error handling with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rspec, rspec-rails

I need to solve a test of my app. Coverage is complaining about a line of code that evaluates the connection to MongoDB (`rescue Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable => _e`) and renders the error.

What do you think I should use to test this:

```
def index
  render json: Complex.all.to_json
rescue Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable => _e
  render json: { error_description: 'no database available' }, status: 503
end
```

I am trying to test with something like:

```
it 'should return an exception' do
  get :index
  expect(response).to raise_exception
end
```

I found that I should use

```
.and_raise(IOError)
```

But I am not sure where to use it to make it fall on the line.
Actually I can make it fall on the exception if I stop Mongo, but that's not the idea.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth this far not to much luck.

I know know that I have to test it with expect(response).to raise_exception

It sound fine, but I havent found the way to make the action to fall on the rescue error.

rescue Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable => _e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach the line of code that handles the exception, stub `Complex.all.to_json` to raise the exception. Since `Complex.all.json` is chained it takes a little extra effort to stub it. Also, since the exception is handled, you can't test that it's raised; instead, test the result of handling it.

```
it 'should handle the exception' do
  all = double
  allow(all).to receive(:to_json).and_raise Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable
  allow(Complex).to receive(:all).and_return all
  get :index
  expect(response.status).to eq(503)
  expect(response.body).to include('no database available')
  # you could test the JSON more thoroughly, but you get the idea
end
```

You could use [`receive_message_chain`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains) to stub `Complex.all.to_json` with less code. I used the long version since it's easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Feel free to add some detail for future mockers and either of us can update our posts.